# How to add plugin dependencies to pom.xml

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I have created a plugin which has other plugins as plugin dependencies in `BuildConfig.groovy`:

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    ....
    plugins {
        build(":release:3.0.0",
            ":rest-client-builder:1.0.3") {
             export = false
        }

        // my dependencies
        compile ':spring-security-core:1.2.7.2'
        compile ":spring-security-ldap:1.0.6"
    }
}
```

How can I make sure that when someone installs my plugin they don't have to install `spring-security-core` and `spring-security-ldap` manually? I want dependency management to do it for them.

Grails 2.3.0

Comment: `dependency-report` of the app using your plugin should show the user what not to install manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already configured it correctly. The release and rest-client-builder builder plugins won't be installed because they're correctly configured to not be exported, but the security plugins are exported since all dependencies are exported by default.

You can see this by running `grails generate-pom` and viewing the generated `pom.xml` file. The jar and plugin dependencies are in the `<dependencies>` block, and there should be entries in `<dependency>` blocks for the "org.grails.plugins" groupId for any transitive plugin dependencies.

Comment: The dependency block in `pom.xml` is empty. It just has `<dependencies />`. Do I maybe need `dependsOn` in the plugin descriptor?

Comment: No, dependsOn isn't used now. Did you run `grails compile` before `generate-pom`?

Comment: Yes, I have (`clean`, `compile`, `generate-pom`). Same results. Here is a sample plugin, maybe you can see if I'm doing something wrong: https://github.com/zoran119/dependency-test

Comment: Looks like a Grails bug, since this works well in earlier versions of Grails. If you don't need 2.3 features (you rarely do when developing plugins) then you can downgrade to 2.0.x/2.1.x/2.2.x and it'll work.

Comment: fixed in 3.0.1 of the release plugin

Comment: Can I just update the `release` plugin in my plugin's `BuildConfig` to `3.0.1`? Or do I need to wait for Grails 2.3.1?

Comment: It was just an issue in the release plugin - if you update the version in your test project and run `grails generate-pom` it has the exported plugin dependencies listed.